# How to deal with instantiated dependencies?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, dependencies, zenject

Dealing with instantiated dependencies.

So a general question:
How to deal with dependencies that is instantiated?

Say I have two functions:

```
public class Manager : ScriptableObject
{
    private var data;
    private void GetDataFromTextAsset() => data = BuildData();
    public bool IsValidInput(var input)
    {
        if(data.SomeAspectIsTrue)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

along with:

```
public class User
{
    public void SomeFunction(var input)
    {
        if(_manager.IsValidInput(input))
            DoStuff();
    }  
}
```

what is the proper way to solve such a dependency, that decouples the two classes, is scalable and testable?

I want to use Zenject, but I'm not sure if that is good for this specific issue?

Also I guess singletons are out the window?

Comment: i think factories would be the way to go.

Comment: Factories are to create instances with their dependencies resolved dynamically, I think this would not be the case. It would depend on how `User` is used

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann Can you expand upon that?
putting GetDataFromTextAsset() into a factory, how do i distribute that instance to all Users?

Comment: yeap, answering with some sample code

Comment: @rustyBucketBay my users just need access to the IsValidInput() method on the manager, which depends on a database build from the text asset, for this reason I would like the manager to be singular.

Comment: a scriptable object is an "instance" in the editor, usually used as config params storage. You can bind the intance and inject that dependency around, 1 min

Comment: is manager a scriptable object (to hold config params)?? or a code class to handle logic?

Comment: because you inherit from `ScriptableObject` but taking into account the sample code and the class name seems to be a manger that you want to be used as a singleton

Comment: but that would couple the two classes tightly? what I thing is the direction i should go in is making a private abstraction on the User called IManager that is injected in the constructor, from an outside factory on DI framework, but i'm a little unsure about the exact approach

Comment: the problem (or one of them) with singletons is that they can't be abstracted? and therefore my code will be hard to test and be tightly coupled?

Comment: "that is injected in the constructor" does not make much sense. Dependency injection consists in inversion of control. What you would need to do is Bind your manager to the container, so that when you use your `User` the dependency is provided. Interface would not make much o a difference for this simple case, but you can do it also

Comment: "will be tightly coupled" you can decouple it with different implementation of an interface later on. I would not worry about that for the moment

Comment: the point is, manager is not a scriptable object, its a normal class right?

Comment: another important thing you need to address is if its a monobehaviour or a c# class (not inheriting from monobehaviour)

Comment: I have a ManagerBehavior : MonoBehaviour

this one have a lot of fields for different managers that inherit from ScriptableObject

I don't know if this is good practise though

Comment: does not seem good practice to me. Check [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html)

Answer (score 1):

For the case of `Manager` being a class used as a singleton, and not as a scriptable object , supposed that your manager is a monobehaviour that needs to be somewhere in the sece in a gameobject, I would do:

```
public class Manager: MonoInstaller
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        InstallManagers();
    }
    
    void InstallManagers() {
        Container.Bind<Manager>().To<Manager>().FromPrefabInstance("Prefabs/scriptFolderName").AsSingle();
        //....bind other managers
    }
}
```

Attach the installer to the `SceneContext` script componenet, in the "MonoInstallers" section.
Then in your `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    [Inject] private Manager _manager; //no need of constructor. Instance is passed in

    public void SomeFunction(var input)
    {
        if(_manager.IsValidInput(input))
            DoStuff();
    }  
}
```

You can check [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/extenject-dependency-injection-ioc-157735) asset, and the github [documetation](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject) which is quite good.

Comment: And if Manager is a `ScriptableObject`? ^^ Tbh in OPs case it doesn't even need to be a `MonoBehaviour` but could be a static class .. so it's a bit unclear what the actual use case is ^^

Comment: It does not make much sense to me the manager to be a `ScriptableObject` (does it?), anyhow in that case the OP could create a class like this `public class ManagerInstaller: ScriptableObjectInstaller<ManagerInstaller>` binding to the container whatever he could need inside.

Comment: Regarding the monobehaviour, yes it is my guess. Anyhow the singleton pattern makes the intance static so the behaviour would be equivalent. On the other hand, afaik, If the OP was using a raw c# static class as a manager, should not be asking about injecting that dependency around, as an static class can be accessed from anywhere, so I thought I could discard that case :)

Comment: Well yesn't ;) because that's my point .. from how OP's code example looks currently it could probably be a `static class` and wouldn't need any references at all .. in particular because `Manager` suggests that there is only one instance anyway .. in which case I also don't see why a Singleton would be bad ^^

Comment: Especially also since `for this reason I would like the manager to be singular. `

Comment: I understood the question was about dependency injection (zenject tag). Its correct that an static class can also deal with that scenario. My point is to provide the most common use case sample code for what I think the OP is asking.

Comment: Also making classes static and accessible from anywhere lead to tightly coupled and hard to maintain code. Topics that the OP seems to care about